# ¿ Cual es la diferencia entre assertEquals y assertSame?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Para cuando compruebo por ejemplo en las pruebas unitarias que un usuario no se creo `assertEquals(0,User::count)` o  `assertSame(0,User::count)`

Comment: esto no corresponde a etiquetas laravel o laravel-5. Mas bien parece de phpunit. Por favor, cambialas.

Answer (score 1):

La diferencia fundamental es que ´assertEquals` responde a comprobaciones de resultado, no de tipo. AssertSame comprueba ademas del valor, del tipo asociado. Si comprobaras una cadena que contiene un numero, contra un entero, assertEquals puede devolverte true. AssertSame comprobaria el tipo, y te devolveria false.

```
assertEquals:   devolveria true si compruebas algo tipo '5' == 5.
assertSame:     devolveria false, porque los tipos no coinciden
```

referencia en stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254180/difference-between-assertequals-and-assertsame-in-phpunit